# Como funciona esta expresión

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy esudiando estructuras de datos con JS y tenemos que crear los metodos de los arrays por cuenta nuestra. Para el metodo push() mi profesor escribe le siguiente codigo, del cual no entiendo el funcionamiento de esta linea ---> this.data[this.length] = item; especificamente el funcionamiento de los corchetes en ese caso.

```
**push(item) {
        this.data[this.length] = item;
        this.length++;
        return this.data
    }**
```

Comment: Acceder a un elemento de Array mediante su índice--->https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `length` te devuelve el total de elementos en el arreglo; en Javascript los índices comienzan en cero y, por lo tanto, te sirve para agregar un elemento al final:

```js
let arreglo = [];

// Ver total de elementos
console.log(arreglo.length); // 0

// Es lo mismo que arreglo[0] = 'Algo'
arreglo[arreglo.length] = 'Algo';

// Ver total de elementos
console.log(arreglo.length); // 1

// Es lo mismo que arreglo[1]... inserta al final
arreglo[arreglo.length] = 'Otra cosa';

// Ver contenido final
console.log(arreglo);
```